# Uninstall Steam Streaming Speakers

Tags: windows-10, digital-audio

I already uninstalled all audio devices in Windows 10 device manager and uninstalled Steam Software completely. After reboot, still the drivers are installed. How can I uninstall drivers manually?
(follow-up question)

```
SteamStreamingSpeakers.sys
SteamStreamingMicrophone.sys
```

[image]

Comment: When you right-clicked to uninstall Steam speakers in Device Manager, did you check the box that said uninstall the drivers? https://www.drivethelife.com/uploadfiles/20180227/delete-the-driver-software-for-this-device.png

Comment: No, I probably missed that checkbox. I have done it now. Solved it. Unfortunately no more audio section in device manager, that mean I cannot select *"Add legacy hardware"* anymore because the submenu is completely gone

Comment: I added it as an answer so you can upvote or accept it. You should be able to click your computer name at very top, then Action, Add legacy hardware

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you right-clicked to uninstall Steam speakers in Device Manager, did you check the box that said uninstall the drivers?

[image]